# Rails setting timeout in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, timeout

In my controller in Rails, I want to download a file into the `public` folder of the project (using the Linux system command `wget`). Then I'd like the file to stay there for an hour, before calling the command `rm` to delete it. Can I set a timeout so that the code execution pauses at some point before resuming later?

Comment: check this screencast. http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not set time out for two reasons:
Firstly, the process will be killed by the web server timeout.
Second, even if you set the timeout is appropriate for your needs, the process responsible for the wait, will eat resources, and will not be available for use. To solve this problem you will have to fork another server process, do you realy need this?

But you can use https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

for example, in your controller

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

def download_using_wget
  ...
  if some_method_to_wget_file
    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

    scheduler.in '1h' do
      some_code_to_rm_file(file)
    end
  end
  ...
```

And some_code_to_rm_file will be started in one hour after you wget file

Comment: Thanks for your answer, antiqe. What I want to do is for the controller to download the file using `wget`, send the file to the user (in effect, let the user download the file), and then delete the file from server. Can I do it without having to set timeout?

Comment: not sure if I understand you correctly? try
after_filter delete_file_after_file_send

Comment: by another words, to send file to user use send_file method instead of giving permanent link to user